# When to use processes, multithreading or neither

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, process

While using Chrome I notice a great many processes. As I understand it Chrome's design entails each plugin, tab and extension to be in its own process.

Is this a more effective approach to just using multithreading such as internet explorer does, or having everything in one process such as Firefox?

I feel the different browsers are a good example for my question. When is it appropriately to use a process for everything vs multithreading vs nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, this multi-processing is done to achieve robustness and security. If one process hangs or crashes, it has absolutely no affect on the other processes (unless it's the process responsible for the UI). This is crucial in an environment where 3rd party extensions might hang, crash or even try to hack your program (different processes don't share the same address space, as opposed to different threads).

Using this approach adds a significant overhead for Inter-Process Communication. When multithreading, passing messages is not a problem, because all threads share the same address space. Passing messages between processes is much harder. Also, the total memory consumption of the program is higher when using processes instead of threads. And then there's the state of the program which is also harder to maintain - if the UI crashes, for instance, all other processes must be shut down. This is not a problem in multithreading, where the main thread exits.

Bottom line - on most cases, using multiple processes is an overkill. However, for better separation of the various tasks, it might be the solution on some cases.

Comment: Giving plugins and extensions separate processes, but surely better error handling code would make sense for tabs rather than simply putting each tab in its own process?

Comment: @Jason, One of the reasons Chrome did that with tabs is to avoid memory leaks - in both IE and FF, closing and opening many tabs caused leaks, which increased the memory consumption and slowed down the process. When you close a tab in Chrome, the whole process is closed, leaving no trace of the memory it had used. You could state memory could be better managed, but then there's the unavoidable fragmantation. I guess once they've figured out the communication, using processes for tabs too was easier than solving other problems.

Comment: @Jason, imagine you allocate 3 chunks of memory, each 1KB. Now you free the first and the last, and want to allocate one straight 2KB chunk. You've just released that much, but there's the other chunk in the middle, so you will now effectively be using 5 KB instead of just 3. Now imagine 1M allocations instead of 5. You can design code that avoids that, but that code might be slow, long and/or hard to maintain. It's a trade-of, and multi-processing is just a way to have both efficient memory operations and efficient code.

Comment: Given the fact that browser tabs are not supposed to communicate with each other, it does not hurt to have them in seperate processes. What is left then? Communication between e.g. Adobe Flash and a tab. Given the fact that Flash is crashing on Macs constantly (since 6 or 7 years and Adobe refuses to fix it) it is quite nice to be able to kill the Flash / Shockwave process and just reload the affected tab. @Jason, it is impossible to "error handle" a rogue plug in "better". The plugin always can do what it wants inside of "its" process.